# 'NoReverseMatch at /blog/' even when asking for a list view the program looks for a detail view

Tags: django, url-routing

This question comes from the book 'Django 2 by example', and has been asked many times before, but even though I checked all the answers I can't fix the problem.

The only thing I am doing differently from the book is creating the 'blog' app inside a 'my_project' project (which contains other apps) rather than inside a 'mysite' project directory.

my error looks like this:

[image]

**my_project/urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from person import views
from accounts.views import RegisterView  # register


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('person/', include('person.urls')),
    path('create/', include('person.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('shopping-cart/', include('shopping_cart.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
]
```

my **blog/urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

my **models.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse


class PublishManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_post')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    object = models.Manager()  # The default manager.
    published = PublishManager()  # My custom manager

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'blog:post_detail',
            args=[
                'self.publish.year',
                'self.publish.month',
                'self.publish.day',
                'self.slug',
            ]
        )
```

my **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,
                             slug=post,
                             status='published',
                             publish__year=year,
                             publish__month=month,
                             publish__day=day)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post})
```

**list.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>My Blog</h1>
{% for post in posts %}
<h2>
    <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
    </a>
</h2>
<p class="date">
    Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
</p>
{{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**details.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
{% for post in posts %}
<p class="date">
    Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
</p>
{{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

and just in case **settings.py**:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'skqmec#*-cflm(s-%3rj&-1ti&ayk)%$ihk5h$3$u=0)ym!&+s'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # created apps

    'person',
    'accounts',
    'shopping_cart',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_project/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'persons/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts/templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_project.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']
DATE_FORMAT = ['%d-%m-%Y']

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/my_project/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Also a screenshot of my project directories

[image]

**please note that if I comment out everything related to the detail view (url patter, view, c.) and I just leave the list view, the path works fine (obviously when clicking on the blog name, which is a link, it doesn't take me anywhere).** The problem is that even if I request the 'local host'/blog address, the program seems to be looking for blog/'the detail view'

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of passing **strings** as `args` in your `get_absolute_url`. Simply change it as:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'blog:post_detail',
            args=[
                self.publish.year,
                self.publish.month,
                self.publish.day,
                self.slug,
            ]
        )
```

and just to clarify it more, as you said, you are seeing this error *even* when you are trying to access the `/blog` (list view); that's because the `{{ post.get_absolute_url }}` in the template of your list view is trying to return `reverse` object to each post, which will cause the error.

Comment: OMG I can't believe I couldn't see that. Thank you :)